# Expected value of Pareto distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

With the Pareto distribution, we have $p(x) = \alpha\lambda^\alpha(\lambda + x)^{-\alpha-1}$.

I am trying to show that $E(X) = \lambda/(\alpha - 1)$. To get this, we integrate $xp(x)$.

Can anyone figure?

Comment: I have edited the post for you. Please familiarize yourself with how such edits work.

Comment: Integration by parts will get you there

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the substitution $u=x+\lambda$.